# How Can I set timeout on Camel Route that uses Camel Bean Component

Tags: routes, timeout

I am programming an application and actually, I am building camel routes for sending messages between endpoints. However, I need set some timeout to the route, because I don't want wait forever by the endpoint's answer. I've searched how to do that but I didn't find yet how to do that using "bean" as described no example below. When you use seda or http component you can just set query options as ?timeout=2000 for example. Can someone help me out with this?

```
  from("direct:someURL").routeId("routeID").to("bean:SomeBean?method=someMethod").to(DUMMY);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with delay concept avail in camel documentation, `http://camel.apache.org/delayer.html`, where use asyncDelay where u can set out delay timeout.